# Can't continue reading from AVAssetReaderOutput after going to background and back to foreground

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, avassetreader

I'm using an `AVAssetReaderOutput` to read samples from an `AVAsset`, do some processing on them, and play the result using a RemoteIO AU.

The problem is that after calling `AudioOutputUnitStop` to pause the playback, then after going to the background and back to the foreground the audio won't start again after calling `AudioOutputUnitStart`. This is due to an error returned from the `copyNextSampleBuffer` method of `AVAssetReaderOutput`, which is called as part of the rendering pipeline.

The `status` property of `AVAssetReader` after calling `copyNextSampleBuffer` is `AVAssetReaderStatusFailed`, and its `error` property is **Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11847 "Operation Interrupted" UserInfo=0x1d8b6100 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop other operations and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Interrupted}**

I'm looking for a solution which won't force me to reinitialize the entire pipeline after coming back to the foreground - Hoping there is such a solution, that `AVAssetReader`s can survive the app going to background and back...

Notes

- The app is entitled to play audio in the background.
- I'm handling audio interruptions - Setting my `AVAudioSession` as the active one both on `AVAudioSessionDelegate`s `endInterruptionWithFlags:` event and whenever the app becomes active. Doesn't make a difference whether I do this or not, getting the same error.

Some code:

AudioPlayer

```
@implementation AudioPlayer
    ...
// Audio Unit Setup
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &_audioUnit);

AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    FillOutASBDForLPCM(audioFormat, 44100, 2, 16, 16, false, false);

AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &audioFormat, sizeof(audioFormat));

AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = RenderCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;
AudioUnitSetProperty(self.audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &callbackStruct, sizeof(callbackStruct));

AudioUnitInitialize(self.audioUnit);
```

AudioReader Setup

```
@implementation AudioReader
    ...
NSError* error = nil;
self.reader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:self.asset error:&error];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = ...
self.readerOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:[self.asset.tracks objectAtIndex:0] outputSettings:outputSettings];
[self.reader addOutput:self.readerOutput];
[self.reader startReading];
```

AudioReader Render Method, called eventually by the RenderCallback function

```
-(BOOL)readChunkIntoBuffer
{
     CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self.readerOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
     if ( sampleBuffer == NULL )
     {
         NSLog(@"Couldn't copy next sample buffer, reader status=%d error=%@, self.reader.status, self.reader.error);
         return NO;
     }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Is this for a compressed audio type?  Some of the hardware audio decompression units on some device models reportedly can not be interrupted without having to be restarted.

Comment: Interesting. It's for reading an `AVAsset` retrieved from an `MPMediaItem`, a song, from the user's iTunes library. So mp3/m4a, I believe both are compressed. Regarding "device models" - This is an issue on an iPhone 5. Is there any available reference for what you're describing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph and AVReader underpinnings are *not* connected/linked whatsoever.  The confusion perhaps comes from that iOS won't "background" (hibernate) a process if it sees the audio graph running (because then audio data would be unable to be generated).  That's why when you stop the audio graph, 2-3 minutes later, iOS will background your process (as of iOS 9).  Presumably, iOS looks at what's going on in your process and decides when your process should be forced to background (via `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler`).

Apple devs decided for whatever reason to make AVReader stop when put into background mode (my best guess is QA).  The good news is that you can detect it and recover when your process exits background mode, but you WILL need to restart your reader and readerOutput again.  First, when AVAssetReaderOutput's `copyNextSampleBuffer` returns NULL, check `AVAssetReader.error.code` for `AVErrorOperationInterrupted`.

The way we pull off a gapless recovery here is when we get to that point, we first calculate the exact time we left off at (easy to do -- just maintain a counter of the total samples already output).  Then, you WILL need to restart your `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetReaderOutput` flow.   But that's no problem since your good development practices would have encapsulated that in a single function that has a seek time as an argument.  In that function, use `AVAssetReader.timeRange` to seek to that time you need to resume at and presto!

Answer (score 3):

There first thing I would try is:

Not calling `AudioOutputUnitStop`? Why don't you leave the graph running and when the audio is paused simply not call

```
[self.readerOutput copyNextSampleBuffer]
```

Instead just fill the buffer with 0's and/or use a render action of kAudioUnitRenderAction_OutputIsSilence for the buffers. Starting and stopping the graph takes time and leads to an unresponsive graph. I never stop the graph while my apps are running. (Unless some serious interruption happens) This may keep the asset reader around and happy.

But I have a hunch that as the `AVAssetReader` is not directly connected to the audio graph (you just happen to request samples and place them in the buffer supplied by the render callback) the problem does not lie with the audio graph being stopped and restarted at all. So the next line of attack I would try is to request samples from an AVAsset, put the app into the background and bring it back to the foreground *without using an AUGraph at all*. This will determine if the problem is related to the `AUGraph` or the app entering a background state.

If something happens that forces you to tear down your `AVAssetReader` you will have to reconnect to the asset. So as you have to write that code another the option I would look at is the one you don't want to do. Reconnect to the `AVAssetReader`, seek to the position you left off at and keep going.

Comment: Actually what I'm doing right now on pause is exactly as you wrote, filling the buffer with 0's, and this way when going to bg and back to fg and starting play again the playback continues properly. The problem with this approach is that a "play" icon remains in the status bar.

Comment: So are you saying that the AVAssetReader is linked to the AUGraph?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by linked? I read from it in the AU's playback callback.

Comment: I find it strange that if you stop the AUGraph the AVAssetReader won't allow you to read samples when you restart the graph. The way that you have set it up means the two should be independent. When you keep the graph running even if you don't request samples the AVAssetReader stays live, but if you stop the graph it dies. Is there any chance the AVAssetReader's class is being garbage collected by ARC?

Comment: Slim chance but if you set the ioActionFlags to be kAudioUnitRenderAction_OutputIsSilence do you still get the playback indication?

Comment: The asset reader isn't being garbage collected by ARC. Also, setting the ioActionFlags as you suggested still displays the play indicator in the status bar. I agree, it is strange! I believe is has something to do with Apple's management of the resources required to play audio, when you to the background with no audio playing iOS might not retain some resources required to continue the playing after going back to fg.